# Visual Studio Enterprise 2017: Ctrl + D doesn't work when starting on a blank line

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2017

The duplicate shortcut in Visual Studio (ctrl+d) seemed really finicky to me, so I did some testing and found that whenever I start a selection on a line with code, it would work fine.

Example:

```
[select start here] //Here is some code

//Maybe some more lines

[select end here]
```

That will duplicate fine. However, if I start on a blank line it does not.

Example:

```
[select start here]

//Here is some code
//Maybe some more lines [select end here]

[or here]
```

Now ctrl+d does nothing. Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 0):

It's neither a bug, nor a feature. **CTRL+D** works fine in both situations. Try once more. Maybe you accidentally pressed other key(s).